# How to signalize a customer to click at one button twice?

Tags: button, click, usability

First I want to make clear that my problem is not a technical question. I want to talk about **usability**.

In my company we have a function to check if a scale works properly. We have the button you see bellow (1) to start a function named scaleCheck(). During the scale check the weight of the scale is set to 0 and then a specified weight is put on the scale **automatically** and when the weight matches the number set in a config file the scale is OK. So when you click on the button, it gets the white border (2) and when the check is finished the button turns normal again (3).

[image]

This is the automatic process, but not every customer has a scale which can put automatically a weight on it. So in this case the customer has to go to the scale an put a weight on it by his own. In our application the customer can configure, if he wants the process to be manual or automatic and the button will adjust to this. So when the configuration is set on **manual** we have to interrupt our function an wait for the customer until he is ready. Because we don't know how many time he will need, he has to click on the button again to tell the application that the process can continue. Therefore we changed the button a bit when we are in manual mode. As you can see below the button (1) changes the image, when the customer clicks the first time on it (2), to show that the weight has to be put on the scale. When he clicks the second time the process proceeds (3).

[image]

So this is the current state. The automatic mode works how the customers imagine it to be, but in the manual mode many people have problems with it and need a lot of time the recognize that they have to **click** on the **same button again** they clicked before.

And here is my question, is there a better way to show the customers that this button should be clicked again. Are there some people who have experiences with a similar kind of functionality? Or is there a better way to do it? I'm open for every idea which comes in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up with the opinion that it is not a intuitive solution to click twice on the button. We solved it by showing the user a message after the first click on the button, and accepting that message is count as the second click. With usability in mind this i by far a better solution and the customers can handle this situation much better.

[image]